# Python: How do I write a function to determine which variable in a dataframe has the highest absolute correlation with a specified column?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matrix, correlation

I would like to write a function to determine which variable in a dataframe has the highest absolute correlation with a specific column. However, I am having difficulty to get the column name from the correlation matrix.

Say that my data, `df`, is as following:

| address | size | rent_price | number_of_bathrooms | number_of_rooms |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| East | 12 | 3400 | 2 | 4 |
| North East | 99 | 4200 | 4 | 4 |
| South | 99 | 4000 | 5 | 5 |

I use `ab_col_matrix = abs(df.corr())` to generate the correlation matrix something like, with column names at the top and the left-hand side of the matrix.

```
1 value value value 
value 1 value value 
value value 1 value 
value value value 1
```

Say that I am interested in the highest correlated column to the size column. My idea is that I would sort the column and take the first row and return the column name with the highest value.

so I tried, `sorted = ab_col_matrix.sort_values('size', ascending = False)`\

then I tried to pick highest one, the `sorted['size'][1]` but it is only returning the value itself but not the column and I am puzzled how I could access that. Here I used `[1]` because `[0]`would return 1 which is the correlation value for its own column.

I would very much appreciate any help where I could gain more knowledge as to how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply select the column for the variable you want and then sort the rows:

```
ab_col_matrix['size'].sort_values(ascending=False)

size                   1.000000
rent_price             0.970725
number_of_bathrooms    0.944911
number_of_rooms        0.500000
Name: size, dtype: float64
```

You can then select the highest correlated value with the following:

```
ab_col_matrix['size'].sort_values(ascending=False).index[1]

'rent_price'
```